# Can't find Documents folder while uploading in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, permissions, files, document

I was uploading my resume to a website and I saw that

> **There was no Documents folder to browse.**

But the Documents folder hasn't been deleted.

> When I go to Files I can see and browse through the Documents folder but when I need to upload something there is no Document folder to browse.

P.S. I have already seen this [How to recover or create deleted 'Documents' folder in Home folder?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/177447/how-to-recover-or-create-deleted-documents-folder-in-home-folder)
But actually everything in my settings is already correct.

Also I remember that while uploading something before I pressed the

**`backspace`**

key while Documents was selected and from that moment I can't find it.SO can that be the issue?
Here is a screen shot of the case.There is no Document folder as you can see.So if anyone could tell how to bring it back.Thanks in advance.
[image: No Documents Folder while uploading]

Here is a screenshot of Files.You can see that the documents folder is present here.
[image: Document folder is present here.]

Answer (score 0):

**Recovering deleted files**

Click on the Trash icon in the Ubuntu Launcher.  Select the files/folders and click the `Restore Restore Selected Items`.

**Locate the Documents folder is it's moved.**

If you don't find your `Documents` folder, you may have inadvertently moved it, as to why you can't find it.  You can search your entire drive with this command sequence:

```
$ sudo updatedb
$ locate /Documents/ | less
```

Search that screen with the arrow keys for familiar files that you are sure were originally in your Documents folder.  If you find your Documents folder you can move it back to the original location with:

```
$ mv /[misplaced location]/Documents ~/Documents
```

Replace `[misplaces location]` with the full pathname of where you find your `Documents` folder.  Don't include the brackets in the example.

**Locate files that were in the Documents folder.**

If you can't find the `Documents` folder by it's name because the name mayh have inadvertently been changed, use the `find` command to find a file that you are sure would be in your documents folder.  This command will show you all the `*odt` files on your system.

```
$ locate -ir "*.odt" | less
```

You can use the search option of the `less` output by hitting the <kbd>/</kbd> key and typing in a search string.  Enter a filter that would include part of the name of your saved resume.

Comment: But the documents folder is in place.I can only not find it while uploading something.I am editing the question.Please check it out.